# How to understand Physical Interpretation of Strong energy condition from its mathematical form?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

The mathematical form of strong energy condition is

(T$_{\alpha \beta}$ - $\frac{1}{2}$ T g$_{\alpha \beta}$) v$^\alpha$  v$^\beta$ $\ge$ 0

where v$^\alpha$ is future directed timelike normalized vector.

I know T$_{\alpha \beta}$ v$^\alpha$  v$^\beta$ represents energy density as observed by an observer.

1. What does $\frac{1}{2}$ T g$_{\alpha \beta}$  v$^\alpha$  v$^\beta$ represent ?
2. I couldn't understand how the equation (T$_{\alpha \beta}$ - $\frac{1}{2}$ T g$_{\alpha \beta}$) v$^\alpha$  v$^\beta$ $\ge$ 0 means matter must gravitate towards matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am bad about physical interpretations of such things but with regards to 2. I can say that this is the so-called focussing theorem: Using Einsteins equations one can rewrite $(T_{ab}-1/2Tg_{ab})v^av^b \geq 0$ as $R_{ab}v^av^b\geq 0$, where $R_{ab}$ is the Ricci-Tensor.

Then in Raychaudhuris equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation one sees that the time derivative of the expansion of geodesics is a sum of negative terms, if the strong energy condition holds, i.e. geodesics will diverge less from each other over time. This is meant by "matter must gravitate towards matter" since Raychaudhuris equation implies that matter will tend to attract.

Answer (score 1):

The strong energy condition is that, for any future-pointing timelike vector,
\begin{equation}
    \left(T_{ab}-\frac{T}{2}g_{ab} \right) V^a V^b \geq 0,
\end{equation}
where $T=T_{ab} g^{ab}$. The geometric interpretation of this energy condition is
\begin{equation}
    R_{ab}V^aV^b\geq 0.
\end{equation}
Written in terms of principal pressure, it gives
\begin{equation}
    \forall i , \quad \rho+p_i\geq 0 , \quad and \quad \rho+\sum_i p_i \geq 0.
\end{equation}
To see its physical meaning, recall the geodesic deviation equation is
\begin{equation}
a^c=-R_{a b d}^c V^a \omega^b V^d.
\end{equation}
The $V^a$ here represents a cluster of timelike geodesics. The $\omega^b$ is the tangent vector of a cluster of the horizontal curve with respect to the timelike geodesic <sup>1</sup>. The $a^c$ characterizes the separation between nearby geodesics and the negative implies nearby geodesics are converging. Then we can define another tensor $a^cw_b=-R_{a b d}^c V^a V^d$, after contracting the index, we get $-R_{a d} V^a V^d$ <sup>2</sup>. This constant also characterizes the separation between nearby geodesics, and similar to $a^c$, a negative value implies converging. Therefore, we can see the physical meaning of SEC is that nearby geodesics never divergent or gravity is attractive in GR.

**Footnotes:**

1. The horizontal curve here represents a curve perpendicular to the cluster of geodesics everywhere, which means for tangent vector $V^a$ of one of the geodesic and the tangent vector $\omega^a$ of the horizontal curve, we have $\omega^a V_a=0$ and $\mathcal{L}_V \omega^a=0$. The second condition means the orthogonality condition holds for any geodesics in that cluster.
2. For a vector $U^a=A\partial^a_r+B\partial^a_{\theta}$, contract $U^a$ with $(dr)_a$ will give A which extracts
   the length of the projection onto $\partial^a_r$. As $V^a$ and $\omega^a$ form a coordinate basis, the contraction $a^cw_b$ could be understood similarly.